# Value from TextBox into Class C#

Tags: c#, class, textbox

I'm new to c# so maybe I'm wondering a stupid question. I'm trying to get a value from a `textBoxFirstname`. and get the value into `ClassRegistrate`.

The reason for this is because I have a Stored Procedure that will put the values that the User writes in textboxUsername into a sql table. But is there any way to check if the value that the user enters in the textBoxUsername enters the `classRegistrate`?

this is how it looks in my `btnRegistrate_click` event:

```
ClassRegistrate registrate = new ClassRegistrate(); 
   
private void btnRegistrate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        registrate.FName = textBoxUsername.Text;
    }
```

And this is what my class look like:

```
public class ClassRegistrate
{
    private string fname;

    public string FName
    {
        get { return fname; }
        set { fname = value; }
    }
}
```

why wont it get the value from my textBox?
thanks for the help

Comment: `registrate.FName = textBoxUsername.Text;` assigns the value of `textBoxUsername.Text` to `registrate.FName` as it is at the time when `btnRegistrate_Click` is called. `registrate` goes out of scope (can't be accessed anymore, and will eventually get purged from memory) at the end of `btnRegistrate_Click`. `MessageBox.Show(FName);` is outside of a method so this code doesn't compile. My only guess is that you're creating a new `ClassRegistrate` elsewhere and expecting to see the value you set. That's like buying two identical new cars, denting one, and looking for the dent on the other car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```csharp
// Define the class ClassRegistrate outside a method 
// so that it can be accessed by other methods
// Therefore it has a bigger scope
private ClassRegistrate registrate2 { get; set; }

private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //ClassRegistrate registrate = new ClassRegistrate();
    //This class definition above will only be accessed inside the function
    //Therefore it has a smaller scope which is limited to this function alone
    
    // assign the class that you already created
    registrate2 = new ClassRegistrate();
    registrate2.FName = textBoxUsername.Text;

    MessageBox.Show(registrate2.FName);
}

public class ClassRegistrate
{
    private string fname;

    public string FName
    {
        get { return fname; }
        set { fname = value; }
    }
    
    //MessageBox.Show(FName);
    //that is a statement and can only exist/executed inside a method/function
}
```

**Example:**

```csharp
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Define the class ClassRegistrate outside a method 
    // so that it can be accessed by other methods
    private ClassRegistrate registrate { get; set; }

    // 1st Button
    private void AssignValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        registrate = new ClassRegistrate();
        registrate.FName = textBox1.Text;
    }

    // 2nd Button
    private void CheckValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = registrate.FName;
        MessageBox.Show(registrate.FName);
    }

    public class ClassRegistrate
    {
        private string fname;
        public string FName
        {
            get { return fname; }
            set { fname = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Output for checking class property value]

Comment: thank you sir for youre time but this will not do so the value of `textBoxUsername` will come into the class. at lest not from my trail.

Comment: @SanderKaupang "will come into the class. at lest not from my trail." can you clarify a bit more.

Comment: Sorry for bad wording i will try again. when I try as you did above but instead put a MessageBox inside the class for and test if fnmae has been set to a value. It goes completely blank when I try the program. Is this the wrong way to see if the value has entered the class?

thank you sir

Comment: @Sander You have to ask a question with a clear problem statement. Please edit your question with a [mcve].

Comment: @SanderKaupang I have updated answer. I create an additional `Button` and `Textbox`. I assign value from `TextBox1` to class, then I call this 2nd function to confirm if the value is availabl in the class property `Fname` by displaying it using `MessageBox` and also displaying the value at `Textbox2`

Comment: Thank you so much for all youre help sir ! :D